# Gmaps.js route with time

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to output the route time from the location, for some reason the route never goes through.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('api/index.php', function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        var map = new GMaps({
            div: '#map',
            lat: 40.715520,
            lng: -74.003409
            zoom: 10
        });
        map.getRoutes({
            origin: [40.715520, -74.003409],
            destination: [data.lat, data.lon],
            callback: function(e) {     
                var time = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < e[0].legs.length; i++) {
                    time += e[0].legs[i].duration.value;            
                }
                $('.time').html(time);
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

Am I do anything wrong?
I have tried this before and it worked fine.

Here is the api output:
`{"lat":40.9238473,"lng":-73.237647}`

Comment: are you sure that data isn't already an object when you try to parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a comma between **lng** and **zoom** property when you create the map:

```
var map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: 40.715520,
    lng: -74.003409,
    zoom: 10
});
```

And you need to use the property **data.lng** insted of **data.lon** when you call the map.getRoutes method:

```
map.getRoutes({
            origin: [40.715520, -74.003409],
            destination: [data.lat, data.lng],
            ... 
        });
```